# Ionic 2 app emulate app on Android V4.2.2 shows whitescreen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, crosswalk-runtime

I am trying to build an **ionic 2** app for **Android**,It works fine for newer versions,but when I tried building it for **V4.2.2** the emulator loads app and shows only white screen.I installed **crosswalk** using both of the below methods:

> ionic browser add crosswalk

and

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

. I have already checked **Ionic Framework's** Forum,where I found out the build will work fine for **v4.4** and with **crosswalk cordova plugin on V4.2.2** and **V4.1**, Does anyone know what could be the issue with the build process.

Comment: it may be issue with security please install cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin and try once

Comment: I had a similar issue with a phone running v4.1.2. Can you check in your package.json if you have these plugins already installed?:


        `"cordova-plugin-device",`
        `"cordova-plugin-console"`
        `"cordova-plugin-whitelist"`
        `"cordova-plugin-splashscreen"`
        `"cordova-plugin-statusbar"`
        `"ionic-plugin-keyboard"`
        `"cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview"`